# ExpressJS one-time transfer of JSON data from server to client

Tags: json, node.js, express, memory-management

I'm building an expressJS application that requires around 50mb (could vary based on compression method) of JSON data to be transferred from the server to the client when the application is initially loaded. I'm having a difficult time finding a way to do this that doesn't crash the client browser due to high memory usage. I've tried using socket.emit which can cause memory usage in chrome to shoot up to 1500mb, which is unacceptable (and this isn't even with the full data set). I've also tried passing the data as an argument of a handlebars render call (on app.get), which seems to work until I have have to eval the data on the client side (which I'm also not a fan of) since it has to be passed as a string. At this point, the memory usage is once again 1500mb+, causing crashes. When I use this amount of data locally, I'm sitting at a comfortable 500-600mb memory usage. So, what's the best way to transfer this data to the client without causing issues?

The data looks something like this:

```
var worldData = {
    'x-164z144': {
         'blocks': {
              'y1': {
                   'color': 16711680,
                   'owner': 'bar456'
               },
               'y5': {
                   'color': 45654815,
                   'owner': 'foo123'
          }
          // possibly more data here in future
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, what's the best way to transfer [50MB of JSON] to the client without causing issues?

The best way is to not do it. You will always have issues when you try to send so much data to the client in one transfer, and you never actually need to do it because the client is very unlikely to need all of that data at once. What you should do is to load only the data you need and when you need more then load more.

You didn't explain what kind of data it is and why you are trying to send it all at once but it's very unlikely that you even need to do it in the first place. You only need to send so much data that is needed immediately and then request more as you need it.

Comment: So, what's the largest amount of data that can be comfortably sent from server to client at once? The way I was planning on building my app all of the data was actually needed at once, but I guess I'll have to work around it if it's not feasible.

Comment: @dyarbrough The performance issues will depend not only on the size but also on the shape of your data, i.e. deeply nested structures vs. flat structures, the types like numbers and strings etc. so e.g. a one long string will not need so much resources a a very deeply nested object. You really need to test it on your data and in your use case. I don't know anything about the data or the use case so it's impossible to say anything more.

Comment: See original post for data structure. The data is very simple, but pretty deeply nested. XZ positions at lowest level, then y positions (height) which give some info about block. Any good resources where I could learn more about this?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this using this guide: http://engineering.curiositymedia.com/blog/better-json-through-streams